# Exibir uma imagem com Java Swing JLabel

Tags: java, swing

Estou tentando exibir uma imagem num app utilizando Swing Java. 
Eu pego alguns frames de um vídeo e os exibo como imagem

```
    private void updateView(){
    Image tempCurrent = imageProcessor.toBufferedImage(currentImage);
    currentImageView.setIcon(new ImageIcon(tempCurrent));

    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "um alo");

}
```

[image: O Jlabel video é a o currentImageView. O container de fora é um JPanel]

não sou programador Java, mas preciso dar manutenção nesse código. 
O procedimento "currentImageView.setIcon" deveria exibir uma imagem no JPanel, mas simplesmente não faz nada. 
A variavel currentImaveView é o JLabel video.
A parte engraçada é que se eu executo o "JOptionPane", ah imagem aparece.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O que é `currentImageView`? Onde é que este componente está?

Comment: Você pode postar mais partes do código?

Comment: currentImageView é um JLabel

Comment: O print está apontando para um link invalido.

Comment: Deve ser porque eu editei a imagem, mas agora está normal.

Comment: Se a imagem aparece quando o JOptionPane aparece, então pode ser uma questão de chamar o "repaint()". Tente isso: Execute sem fazer o JOptionPane aparecer, depois minimize a Janela e maximize ela (isso causará um repaint), ou, redimensione ela (deverá causar vários repaints).

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza este código se queres por uma imagem dentro do jlabel:

```
// Import ImageIcon     
ImageIcon iconLogo = new ImageIcon("Images/YourCompanyLogo.png");

"nome da variable da jlabel".setIcon(iconLogo);
```

Comment: você leu a pergunta? Ele já fez dessa forma, o problema não era esse..